# Flattening records in Unix

Tags: unix, awk, normalization

How to flatten records in UNIX by combining 2 rows and splitting another.?

There are a set of records in file which needs to be flattened.

```
IMP*1000*000***12>D>1*N*A*Y*I~
HO*DK>4019*DF>25002~
IMP*1001*000***12>D>1*N*A*Y*I~
HO*DK>25000*DF>4139*DF>4019*DF>29631*DF>311*DF>4289*DF>42731~
IMP*1002*000***12>D>1*N*A*Y*I~
HO*DK>412*DF>4289*DF>2449*DF>4019~
```

The output should look like

```
1000|1|DK|4019|
1000|2|DF|25002|
1001|1|DK|25000|
1001|2|DF|4139|
1001|3|DF|4019|
1001|4|DF|29631|
1001|5|DF|311|
1001|6|DF|4289|
1001|7|DF|42731|
1002|1|DK|412|
1002|2|DF|4289|
1002|3|DF|2449|
1002|4|DF|4019|
```

Second field in the output is sequence numbers. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a matter of identifying and storing the code from the first of each pair of lines to go on each output line with the individual values parsed from the second of each pair of lines. The code is more succinct if we set the field separator to `*` and the output field separator to `|` at the start.

```
BEGIN   {   FS = "*"; OFS = "|" }

/^IMP/  {   code = $2 }

/^HO/   {   for (i = 2; i <= NF; i++) {
                sub("~","",$i)
                split($i,x,">")
                print code,(i-1),x[1],x[2] "|"
            }
        }
```

... which, given the input shown in the question, produces the output:

```
11824393C1054263R0|1|DK|4019|
11824393C1054263R0|2|DF|25002|
11747326C1038424R0|1|DK|25000|
11747326C1038424R0|2|DF|4139|
11747326C1038424R0|3|DF|4019|
11747326C1038424R0|4|DF|29631|
11747326C1038424R0|5|DF|311|
11747326C1038424R0|6|DF|4289|
11747326C1038424R0|7|DF|42731|
11972831C1024443R0|1|DK|412|
11972831C1024443R0|2|DF|4289|
11972831C1024443R0|3|DF|2449|
11972831C1024443R0|4|DF|4019|
```

... as required.

Comment: @ashokviswanathan: Glad to help. If you find an answer to be satisfactory, you can check it as accepted, which will save other people attempting to find other answers to the same problem.